# Google Earth Engine: Finding the right image dimensions to get max resolution on satellite imagery

Tags: javascript, pixel, raster, satellite-image, google-earth-engine

I am new to Google Earth Engine, and was trying to get Landsat imagery for the entire Democratic Republic of Congo. The project involves some computer vision and image segmentation, so I need to get the highest resolution possible.

I have some code that I developed from the earth engine to make a composite from 1 year of landsat imagery posted below.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[29.70703125, -3.3160183381615123],
      [24.609375, -3.4476246666468526],
      [24.8291015625, -7.732765062729807],
      [29.970703125, -7.645664723491028]]]);

// Composite 6 months of Landsat 8.

Map.setCenter(  26.362312, -4.643601, 5);
var boundingBox = geometry.bounds(1)
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');
var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: L8.filterDate('2015-1-1', '2015-7-1').filterBounds(geometry),
  asFloat: true});
var region = ee.Geometry(geometry.getInfo())
                        .toGeoJSONString()
var params ={
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      region:region
    }
Export.image(composite,'congo_test',params);
```

The problem is that each time I run the script it asks me for the `scale` value. So I ask for the highest resolution, but the query keeps erroring out because it says that I have exceeded the maximum pixel limit for the image export.

So basically I need to figure out how to carve up congo into a set of blocks for which Earth Engine allows me to pull max resolution composite imagery. Does anyone know how I can calculate the correct size polygons to fit the bill?

Comment: Just increase the `maxPixels` parameter to something like `1e12`. That will let you export the landsat image with 30 m, aka the max resolution.

Comment: Oh cool. So I can set the max pixels in the 'params' variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Val indicated, the solution here was to apply the `maxPixels` parameter to the `param` variable in the javascript. The final javascript code below will automatically break up the image into chunks based upon the maxPixels parameter.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[29.70703125, -3.3160183381615123],
      [24.609375, -3.4476246666468526],
      [24.8291015625, -7.732765062729807],
      [29.970703125, -7.645664723491028]]]);

// Composite 6 months of Landsat 8.

Map.setCenter(  26.362312, -4.643601, 5);
var boundingBox = geometry.bounds(1)
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1');
var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: L8.filterDate('2015-1-1', '2015-7-1').filterBounds(geometry),
  asFloat: true});
var region = ee.Geometry(geometry.getInfo())
                        .toGeoJSONString()
var params ={
      crs: 'EPSG:4326',
      maxPixels: 1e12,
      region:region
    }
Export.image(composite,'congo_test',params);
```

This worked for me. Thanks @Val.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a scale in the export parameters.  Composites don't have a native scale anymore, so they default to 1 degree per pixel.  Since you started with landsat, you probably want a scale of 30.